# Correct syntax for rmarkdown chunk argument "R.options"

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm looking for a working example of usage of the "R.options" argument to a knitr chunk. Something like:

````
```{r chunk_fu, echo=FALSE, R.options="width=40"}
head(mtcars)
```
````

or

````
```{r chunk_fu, echo=FALSE, R.options="scipen=-5"}
1234567890
```
````

It's this part that does not seem to be working:
`R.options="width=40"`

Do I need parentheses? More quotes? less quotes? where should they go?

In the end, my true goal is to set the output width of text to 40 characters, in a standard HTML output file. Maybe this is not the right way, but I can't find an example of the right syntax for `R.options`, so thought I'd ask.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use a named list with the values in quotes:

````
```{r chunk_fu, echo=FALSE, R.options = list(scipen="-5")}
1234567890
```
````

Note to use the named list with all values (e.g. "-5" or "40") in quotes.

Comment: woohoo! Thanks @J_F (i think you mean values in *quotes*, not *parentheses*) - but the example is right. I'm sure I tried every other possible permutation of quotes, parentheses, commas, and unary operators to get it to work.